# The foot of the height in an orthocentric tetrahedron is the orthocenter of a face.

Tags: geometry

Consider a tetrahedron with a right-angle corner (like the corner of a cube) at $D$. Prove that the foot of the height from $D$ to the face ABC is the orthocenter of $ABC$.

Is this well-known?[image]

Answer (score 3):

$BD\perp DAC$ (plane) so in particular $BD\perp AC$

$DH\perp ABC$ (plane) so $DH\perp AC$

So $AC \perp BD$ and $AC\perp DH$ so $AC\perp DHB$ (plane). In particular $AC\perp BH$, so $BH$ is altitude. Similarly for the other vertices, so $H$ is orthocenter.

And yes, this is well-known (at least by any participant in a Math Olympiad)